# flatten an array recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I tried to implement an array flatten function recursively. Here is the code:

```
function flatten(arr) {
  var flatArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
      flatArr.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
    } else {
      flatArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return flatArr;
}


console.log(flatten([1, 2, 3, 4, [5]]));
/*
result: [1, 2, 3, 4]
expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
*/
```

But I don't know why the result is not correct. Please help me explain it.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't assign the returned array from `.concat` to your `flatArr` var. see a working example inside my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `concat()` method returns a **new** array comprised of the array
>   on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s)
>   provided as arguments.

`flatArr.concat(...)` doesn't change `flatArr`... you need to assign it like so:

`flatArr = flatArr.concat('flatten(arr[i]));`

Here is a working example with 3 levels deep array:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  var flatArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
      flatArr = flatArr.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
    } else {
      flatArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return flatArr;
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,[7,8]]];
var flatten = flatten(arr);

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(flatten));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You can read more about [Array.concat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) here

Answer (score 4):

You have to assign the returned `array` after performing the `concat`,

```
 if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
      flatArr = flatArr.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
```

`concat` will not edit the source array. It will give you a new copy. So we have to assign it back to the `source array` manually.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you like a real recursive solution:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return [];
    }
    var a = arr.shift();
    return (Array.isArray(a) ? flatten(a) : [a]).concat(flatten(arr));
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(flatten([1, 2, 3, 4, [5]])) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(flatten([1, [2, 3, [4, 5]], 6, 7, [8]])) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, hope it helps! :)

```js
function flatten(array) {
    let result = [];
    array.forEach(el => {
       if(el instanceof Array){
          result.push(...flatten(el));
        }else result.push(el)
     });
     return result
}
console.log(flatten([1, [2, 3, [4]]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I am influenced by the [Nina Scholtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)'s answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681232/5018572) above and made a tail call safe recursive flat array function which avoid using any iteration in it:

```js
'use strict'

function flatten(arr, flatArr = []) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return flatArr;
  }

  var [head, ...rest] = arr;

  if (Array.isArray(head)) {
    head.push(...rest);
    
    return flatten(head, flatArr);
  } else {
    flatArr.push(head);
  }

  return flatten(rest, flatArr);
}

var test = [1,2,[3,4,[5,[[[6,[[[7]]]]]]]]]
console.log(flatten(test));
```

Comment: What is "*tail safe*"? Also notice that spread syntax always does iteration, it's just hidden from view. Doing list-like structural recursion with `[head, ...rest] = arr` is actually very inefficient (`O(n²)`).

Comment: it's a tail call safe, I corrected my missing word. Thanks god I never mention it's the performant solution. You can simply using `shift()` to get first element and use the argument `arr` for the rest of the code. That way It'll be more performant.

Comment: `shift()` is just as inefficient. It moves all the array elements by one position.

Comment: I'd rather see the benchmark result instead of saying it's inefficient.

Comment: There's nothing to benchmark about time complexity. It might be very fast for small arrays!

Comment: very well, performance is whole another topic anyone welcome to change performance pain points.

Answer (score 0):

Loop array until all items get flatten, It's a different solution, not exactly what asked in the question.

```
// loop until all items are flatten
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[i])) {
        // flatten until there are no more nested
        data = data.concat.apply([], data);
        i--;
        len = data.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on another (possibly better performant) answer.

I used `push`, and `pop` for modifying the arrays (given and final arrays) because they're more performant array operations compare to `shift` for remove the first element from given array, or **spread operator** for merging arrays or combining it with destruction to simulate `shift` method.

I also used `push` method for merging arrays (credit to this post: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/big-o-complexity-of-concat-vs-push-apply-inside-loops/33513).

There's a catch though: result array is reversed. `push` and `pop` adds/removes last item therefore I created the final array in reversed order. For this reason I called `.reverse` at the end.

`reverse` is executed after all flattening operations are completed, so it won't increase the complexity.

Here is the solution:

```js
function flatten(arr, flatArr = []) {
  if (arr.length === 0){
      return flatArr.reverse();
  }
  
  var lastItem = arr.pop();

  if(Array.isArray(lastItem)){
    Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, lastItem);  
    return flatten(arr, flatArr);
  } else {
      flatArr.push(lastItem);
  }
  
  return flatten(arr, flatArr)
}

var array1 = [1,2,[3,4,[5,[[[6,[[[7, [8, 9, [10, [11,[12, [13, [[[[14,[15, [[16,[17]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]];
var array2 = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1],2,3]]]],4],5]]]],6],7],8],9]],10],11],12],13],14],15],16]]],17];


console.log(flatten(array1));
console.log(flatten(array2));
```